# Overlap Button on Buttons using Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have here a problem on overlapping the button on another button.
I wanted to follow the pic I've attached below[image]

Codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/buttons-changing-forked-jplmt?file=/src/Table/index.js)

```
const MainButton = styled.button`
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  & > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;

const IconButton = styled.button`
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  & > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to absolutely position `IconButton` relative to `MainButton` it needs to be rendered as a child of `MainButton`.

```
<MainButton type="button">
  <img
    src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg"
    alt="test"
  />
  <IconButton>+</IconButton>
</MainButton>
```

Next adjust the positioning of `IconButton`.

```
const IconButton = styled.span`     // <-- use span since nesting button is invalid
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;                // <-- center text vertically
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;                        // <-- position halfway across parent
  bottom: 0;                        // <-- position at bottom of parent
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); // <-- translate to center button

  & > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;
```

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` rule on parent `MainButton`.

[image]

[image: Edit overlap-button-on-buttons-using-styled-components]

### Update

Move the image to be a background image and tweaked the positioning.

```
const MainButton = styled.button`
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: ${({ src }) => `url(${src});`}
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  & > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;

const IconButton = styled.div`
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  & > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;
```

[image]

[image: Edit overlap-button-on-buttons-using-styled-components (forked)]

Comment: Thanks Drew. I forked your codesandbox and I changed the "src" in image tag. The problem is, it goes outside the `<MainButton>`. It should just be inside the `<MainButton>` https://codesandbox.io/s/overlap-button-on-buttons-using-styled-components-forked-vhuth?file=/src/Table/index.js

Comment: @Joseph Ok, I moved the image to be a background image for the button and updated the positioning of the (+) decorator.